# Sign into existing Laravel back-end with Parse

Tags: php, android, ios, laravel-4, parse-platform

I am interested in expanding a Laravel 4.2 web app into the realm of mobile apps, allowing simple things such as the ability for **existing** users to sign in (but not sign up) and receive push notifications (simple at first for beta testing). I am very intrigued by Parse.com for their push notification capability but do not want to have to manage two sets of users - Parse and Laravel. Further, this app will be locked down to subscribers - it cannot be a free for all when it comes to user registration.

On the feature list for Parse Core it mentions connecting users via "traditional logins" but I cannot find an example of this anywhere. By "traditional login" do they mean sending a username and password to a remote back end? Or is that their way of referring to logging in with Parse users? Is it possible to connect Parse to a remote API such as my Laravel project (something along the lines of sending POST data with username and password and returning an auth token)?

I'd appreciate any advice on this or links to tutorials/documentation/etc. I have searched quite a bit and cannot seem to find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the SDKs to login a user either using a username/password or using Facebook.

- [Android login](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-login)
- [iOs login](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-login/iOS)
- [REST login](https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-login)

I would suggest you log the user in on the client device so that their device is registered to allow push notifications.

You can also use the REST API in your server code to do other things, such as creating the User and sending push notifications.

You can use Roles to limit things, e.g. create a "Subscriber" role and set permissions based on that Role.

Comment: I have skimmed the documentation and it all seems to refer to logging in users with the Parse user system - I want to log them in with my existing database/Laravel app. I do not want to use Parse to handle my user log-in everywhere nor do I want to manage two sets of users - so is this possible with Parse?